# Bash configuration

Tags: bash, terminal, config, git-bash, oh-my-posh

I try to configure my bash shell with oh my posh.
But I get this error

```bash
Oh My Posh Error: CreateFile C:\Users0snow\my-profile.omp: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

.bashrc file:

````bash
eval "$(oh-my-posh --init --shell bash --config $HOME/my-profile.omp)" ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Is there something wrong with your `$HOME`variable? I don't think it should be `C:\Users0snow` but `C:\Users\snow`, no?